# Ajax Logging on any site

Tags: ajax, logging

All,

Is there a way to log all clicks(like hyperlinks,buttons,.....) performed by the user on the client on any webpage and send it to server for logging purpose.If so please direct me to a sample code for it.

Thanks......

Comment: I'm I the only one who understand this question as "I want to log all actions on all page not just mine"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the Google Analytics script in your file and reap its benefits.

Comment: Can u please indicate any small script.I 2 got to know today that this can be done through google analytics...Thanks

Comment: Check their site : http://www.google.com/analytics/

Google analytics is just a script provided by the google which you have to include in your site. The complete details is given in their site. Check the link given above. Once you include the script in your site the analysis reports and stuff can be seen in the same site (again check the link).
It pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are going to build a extension (or some greasemonkey script) for some browser you won't be able to do that for any web page the user visits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all clicks result in a server request, then why not just scan the access logs of the web server?

You can add a uniquely identifying id in each url in order to distinguish between users.

Comment: In this case Take an example of a user clicking an hyperlink and thru jwuery perform aome action on client side and display the results(ex:open a popup or sumthing else)to log this i need sum sort of an logging infrastructure.